# Arch Linux Manjaro: npm start not detecting chrome and returning ENOENT error

Tags: arch-linux, manjaro, npm, javascript

I am using Manjaro and have downloaded google-chrome-stable from the AUR package. Even though google chrome is set as a default browser, npm start still defaults to opening firefox, after I deleted firefox I start receiving the following error

```
Starting the development server...

node:events:342
      throw er; // Unhandled 'error' event
      ^

Error: spawn /usr/bin/firefox ENOENT
    at Process.ChildProcess._handle.onexit (node:internal/child_process:282:19)
    at onErrorNT (node:internal/child_process:480:16)
    at processTicksAndRejections (node:internal/process/task_queues:83:21)
Emitted 'error' event on ChildProcess instance at:
    at Process.ChildProcess._handle.onexit (node:internal/child_process:288:12)
    at onErrorNT (node:internal/child_process:480:16)
    at processTicksAndRejections (node:internal/process/task_queues:83:21) {
  errno: -2,
  code: 'ENOENT',
  syscall: 'spawn /usr/bin/firefox',
  path: '/usr/bin/firefox',
  spawnargs: [ 'http://localhost:3000' ]
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If you are using `react-scripts` as your toolchain, you can set the `BROWSER` environment variable to the browser of your choosing.

To make it work with all your projects, edit your `.bashrc` file and add :

```
export BROWSER=chrome
```